# Jackson XML : How to deserialize XML using JacksonXmlElementWrapper with multiple wrapper class

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a XML String that I need to deserialize

```
<LOC attribute="example">
   <VehAvail>
      <VehAvailCore>
         <Fees>
             <Fee att1="a" att2="b" att3="c"/>
             <Fee att1="x" att2="y" att3="z"/>
         </Fees>
      </VehAvailCore>
    </VehAvail>
</LOC>
```

This is what I am  trying with but I don't have exact solution for adding the upper two wrappers  and

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Fees")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Fee")
private List<Fee> fees = new ArrayList();
```

How can I deserialize it into Java POJO class with JacksonXML Annotation ?

Answer (score 3):

#### There can be only one.

Ok, [Highlander](http://highlander.wikia.com/wiki/There_can_be_only_one) aside, there can really be only one wrapper around a list of elements.

In your example, you could define just 3 classes: `LOC`, `VehAvailCore`, and `Fee`, and specify wrapper `VehAvail` around `VehAvailCore`, and wrapper `Fees` around `Fee`.

Of course, it all depends on cardinalities (`minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`) and what other optional elements/attributes are possible for `VehAvail`, `VehAvailCore`, and `Fees`. Without knowing the full spec, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: its a single occurrence and VehAvail, VehAvailCore and Fees don't have any attributes

Comment: @sbhatt If `Fees` is `maxOccurs="1"` (the default if not specified), then it is not a list, and `VehAvailCore` is by definition **not a wrapper** around a `Collection`. See javadoc of [`JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html): *"Annotation that is similar to JAXB `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper`, to indicate wrapper element to use (if any) **for Collection types** (arrays, `java.util.Collection`)."* --- Same for `VehAvail`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, here my intent is to wrap list of class <Fee> Objects in the wrapper Fees